# Check if a field of a file exists in another file and update the the first file's specific column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have 2 files as below:

`a.txt` (tab delimited and it has 3 columns and too many lines):

```
 city   plate   region
 istanbul   36  marmara
 trabzon    61  karadeniz
```

`b.txt` (comma delimited and it has 4 columns and too many lines):

```
name,city,age,nationality
mehmet,trabzon,,
murat,istanbul,,
john,london,,
```

What I want to do is: check if the 2nd column (`city` field) of `b.txt` exists in `a.txt` (in first column - `city`) and if it exists in `a.txt`; update the file `b.txt` and set 4th column (`nationality`) to "turkish".
So expected output:

```
name,city,age,nationality
mehmet,trabzon,,turkish
murat,istanbul,,turkish
john,london,,
```

I tried following command but it did not generated the desired output:

```
nawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } FNR == NR {x[$1] = $1; next;} {FS=OFS=","} FNR>1{if ($2 in x) {($4 = "turkish")} } 1' a.txt b.txt
name,city,age,nationality
mehmet,trabzon,,
murat,istanbul,,
john,london,,
```

I need to find the mistake in my command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works fine. My guess is the first file has spaces instead of tabs as separators.

Remove the useless `BEGIN { FS = "\t" }` to check if it is the case.

Comment: You are totally right, it worked after removing the BEGIN { FS = "\t" } phrase.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` (notice that the first file `a.txt` has to be loaded into memory completely):

```
awk -F"[\t, ]" 'FNR==NR&&NR!=1{a[$1]="turkish"}
  FNR!=NR{OFS=",";if(FNR!=1){$NF=a[$2]};print}' a.txt b.txt
```

---

- `-F"[\t,]"` sets awks delimiter to tab and comma
- `FNR==NR&&NR!=1` only applies to the first file `a.txt` and ignore the first line (header)

  - `a[$1]="turkish"` set in an array called `a` the index to the first field `$1`
- `FNR!=NR` applies only to the second file `b.txt`
- `OFS=","` set the output field separator
- `if(FNR!=1)` only do something when it's not the header line
- `$NF=a[$2]` set the last field to the previously saved value `turkish` if it exists in the array
- `print` and print the line if the value existed or not

---

The output:

```
name,city,age,nationality
mehmet,trabzon,,turkish
murat,istanbul,,turkish
john,london,,
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it did not work. With awk (empty result):
`bash-3.00$ awk -F"[\t,]" 'FNR==NR&&NR!=1{a[$1]="turkish"}  FNR!=NR{OFS=",";if(FNR!=1){$NF=a[$2]};print}' a.txt b.txt






`
With nawk (b.txt file not updated):
`bash-3.00$ nawk -F"[\t,]" 'FNR==NR&&NR!=1{a[$1]="turkish"}  FNR!=NR{OFS=",";if(FNR!=1){$NF=a[$2]};print}' a.txt b.txt
name,city,age,nationality
mehmet,trabzon,,
murat,istanbul,,
john,london,,`

Comment: @Murat Possible you have `s`pace separator instead `t`ab so just add `s`pace to delimiters `[ \t,]`

Comment: A some shorter `awk -F"[ \t,]" 'FNR==NR{if(NR!=1)a[$1]=1;next}
  $2 in a{$NF="turkish"}1' OFS="," a.txt b.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sed`

```
sed -n 's|\(.*\S\)\s\+[0-9].*|/\1/s/$/turkish/|p' a.txt |
sed -f - b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr   -s \[:blank:] , <a.txt|    #dont mess with weird columns
cut  -d, -f1  |  sort -u   |    #drop all but unique first column entries
sed  -e's/[]*^\./$[]/\\&/g'\    #handle any regex metachars properly
     -e's/.*/^[^,]*,&,/'   |    #match only second column
grep -nf - -- b.txt        |    #get line numbers at head of matched lines
sed  -e's/:.*/be/'         |    #keep only matched line numbers + 'be'
sed  -f - -eb -e:e         \    #branch away or append turkish
     -e's/$/turkish/' -- b.txt
```

---

```
mehmet,trabzon,,turkish
murat,istanbul,,turkish
john,london,,
```